# How to generate key hash for facebook in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, openssl, facebook-login, sha1

I am trying to generate **key hash** for implementing **Facebook login** feature in app

I am writing the following but error appears:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Jaffs\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\openSSl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\openSSl\bin\openssl" base64
```

**Error**:

```
At line:1 char:137
```

- ... roid\debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\openSSl\bin\openssl" sha1 -b ...
- ```
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:176

- ... debug.keystore" | "C:\Program Files\openSSl\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary ...
- ```
                                                           ~~~~
  ```

Unexpected token 'sha1' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:191

- ... openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\openSSl\bin\openssl" base64
- ```
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At line:1 char:230

- ... openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\openSSl\bin\openssl" base64
- ```
                                                                 ~~~~~~
  ```

  Unexpected token 'base64' in expression or statement.

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline

I checked the path of **OpenSSl** is correct.
I tried many solutions but not worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifing the openssl file extension.
Type `.exe` at the end of the openssl path. 
I did that and it provided me the key.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing the double quotes ("") in your path, then adding ".\" to the first of line if needed,

Eg:

.\keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\MyPC.android\debug.keystore | D:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | D:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl base64

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).